# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "package.MainActivity" on brand new project

Tags: java, android, classnotfoundexception

This is terribly frustrating. I have created new project in Android Studio - Empty Activity template so i get one Activity file with its layout file where is one TextView. When i launch the project i get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{package/package.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "package.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/package-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/package-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I tried File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart it didn't help.

It is astounding why some error happens on brand new template project.. I am confused..

I created two new projects, it happens on both of them.

Comment: Have you added it in the manifest?

Comment: Hi, it is template project, it is already in manifest both the package name on manifest element and activity element with proper activity name ".MainActivity"

Comment: is this your first project? is this your first time installing android studio? has this happened before?

Comment: Create a new package and copy the MainActivity there. and then change the package name in manifest as well to reflect the new proper path. it should work

Comment: Hi Anthony, no it is not my first project, i have had opened another project and working with it until now but then i decided to create new project and test something. It never happened before.

Comment: show your manifest file @luky

Comment: clean of project fixed it, thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once it happened to me as well. I just cleaned the project and rebuilt it and everything then went perfect so I suggest you do the same.

Follow below steps:

1. select build (this option is available on the top of android studio)
2. select clean project and wait for gradle process end
3. once gradle process ends rebuild it.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Hi Abdul, thank you Clean of project worked, i thought i did it already but it seems i didnt

Comment: I am glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Checek in your **AndroidManifest.xml** file your activity is registered or not.
If not then do it.

Comment: Hi, it is a template project, so manifest is automatically generated and contains everything it should contain.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry it is not a big problem, you just clean the project . First step is to click on the Build options in the android studio.Then you click on the clean project and then run your app.It will work.I hope this method solves your problem.

Comment: Hi Prabha, thank you Clean of project really worked.